# How do I make an int appear in LogCat in Eclipse with Java/Android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Here is my code for Xcode and iOS:

```
NSLog(@"EAN-8: %d", finalNumber);
```

How do I do the same thing on Java so it appears in the LogCat?

Thanks.

Comment: do you want to view the android logcat ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Log.d("MyApplication", String.format("EAN-8: %d", finalNumber));
```

The first parameter is called the tag, which you can use to filter Logcat output if needed.  See [the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) for more info/log severities.